# getCameraInstance(0) returns null

Tags: java, android

The basic idea is if no face detected,it should return to Main(reset Activity) but after returning back to main ,getCameraInstance(0) returns null.

If i want to back to Main ,it will call the onPause() and release the cam and after main re-created the backCamera is already relased and it should problem-free create a new instance of back camera.Am i wrong ?

Thanks

ps :i get java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service and that means i didnt release the camera correctly but i cant find my error.
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
....
private Camera mCameraBack=null;
private CameraPreviewBack mPreviewBack;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(mCameraBack==null){
            mCameraBack=getCameraInstance(0);
        }

        try{

            mPreviewBack=new CameraPreviewBack(this,mCameraBack );
            previewBack=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_back);
            previewBack.addView(mPreviewBack);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreate");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

public void capture(View view){

mPreviewBack.takePicture();
...
}

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();

        if (mCameraBack != null) {
            mCameraBack.stopPreview();
            mCameraBack.release();
            mCameraBack = null;
        }

        if (mPreviewBack != null) {
            previewBack.removeView(mPreviewBack);
            mPreviewBack = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        if (mCameraBack == null) {
            mCameraBack = getCameraInstance(0);
        }

        if (mPreviewBack == null) {
            mPreviewBack=new CameraPreviewBack(this,mCameraBack );
            previewBack.addView(mPreviewBack);

        }
    }

public static Camera getCameraInstance(int cameraId){

        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(cameraId); 
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CameraPreviewBack extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
...

public CameraPreviewBack(Context context,Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera=camera;
        this.context=context;
        mHolder=getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Surface created");

        try {
            if(mCamera!=null){
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mHolder failure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Surface changed");
        configureCamRotation();
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

public void takePicture(){
         ..
        task.execute();
        try {
            task.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        }
    task.cancel(isFinished);
}

private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
        PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
            ....
            if(!detected){
             Intent intentMain=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
             intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             context.startActivity(intentMain);
            }
...


}
   private class TakePictureTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, getPictureCallback());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000); // 3 second preview
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return null;
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

releasing camera onDestroy and changing Intents in onPostExecute method of Asynctask solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

newer swallow exceptions 
like here:

> catch (Exception e){
>           }

Print this exception Log.d(TAG, "Error when init camera", e); and maybe you will get:

- Runtime Exception http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)

Comment: to shorten the code i deleted logs.I have already so implemented